# I need to change the date output format on SQL withing this script from yyy-mm-dd to dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT [WHO].PERSONNUM EMPID
              , [SHIFTSTARTDATE] STDT
              , [SHIFTENDDATE]       ENDDT
              , GETDATE() [WHEN]
FROM   [WFCDB].[dbo].[SHIFTASSIGNMNT]    AS [WHN]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [WFCDB].[dbo].VP_ALLPERSONv42 AS [WHO]
     ON [WHN].EMPLOYEEID = [WHO].EMPLOYEEID
WHERE  DATEPART(m, [SHIFTSTARTDATE]) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
  AND  DATEPART(yyyy, [SHIFTSTARTDATE]) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
  AND  DELETEDSW <> 1)
```

Comment: Please tag your dbms.

Comment: Added sql server tag based on code used

Comment: Ideally, keep it as a `datetime` (which doesn't **have** a format) and have whatever is *consuming* the result set deal with transforming it into a string, if it needs to. It's at the point of transforming dates into strings that formatting matters and ideally, you do it as late as possible so that, if you possibly want or need to process it as datetime data later, you don't have to *undo* the conversion to string and potentially add more formatting issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CONVERT to format dates:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 104)  --> dd.mm.yy
```

Take a look at [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

But I usually format my dates in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 104)
```

check this link other formats
https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/